# Show that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),\; A=\{x\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\mid x\text{ is infinite}\}$ have the same cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Well, one direction is pretty trivial, we could just take $id_A$ as an injective function.

How should I approach the other direction?

Comment: $id_A : A \rightarrow A$

Comment: @RiccardoAllegrone If you mean $id_A : A \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ Thats the trivial part I was talking about

Comment: I mean that $id_A$ goes from $A$ to $A$, not to $\mathcal{P}$. Maybe you want to use inclusion.

Comment: @RiccardoAllegrone Thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal P(\Bbb N)\setminus A$ is countable, and one could use that fact to play Hilbert's Hotel.

Or just map $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)\to A$, $X\mapsto 2X\cup (2\Bbb N+1)$.

Comment: Hey Hagen. Thanks for your comment. 
Could you elaborate furthermore on your map? I didn't quite get it.

Answer (score 0):

As Hagen said, the set of finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ is countable, and so, the set of co-finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ is countable($B=\{x\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\mid {\Bbb N}\setminus x\text{ is finite}\}$), because $|\Bbb N\times2|=|\Bbb N|$, take $G:({\cal P}(\Bbb N)\setminus A)\cup B\to B$ a bijective function.

Let $F:{\cal P}(\Bbb N)→A$ define like this: if $x∈({\cal P}(\Bbb N)\setminus A)\cup B$ then $F(x)=G(x)$, elsewhere $F(x)=x$. $F$ is a bijection